# Keep Outlook calendar attachments up to date without spamming users with e-mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications

I work in a new company and they use Outlook and we have many workshops with many participants and to effectively work in those meetings we need to prepare and update materials several times and several days in advance before those meetings.

Sometimes meetings are scheduled weeks in advance, but some last minute updates on materials by different departments are just unavoidable.

Some people don't want to get calendar up dates because of the dozens of spam e-mails from outlook every week.

Other people need those updates desperately to work on the meeting's content and supporting material.

I often have to go to meetings with old presentations and supporting materials, because people are not allowed to send updates, because the huge amount of outlook spam.

And there is absolutely no need for notifications in our use case, of course everyone wants the updated material and not the old material.

Same is true for cancelled meetings. I don't want to go to a cancelled. I have to manually remove it from my calendar instead of getting a real update, I want it removed automatically. And why do I get spam? Why cannot Outlook just do it. Just update my calendar there is no User interaction needed.

**Is there any way how to turn off this spam**, so I can finally have up to date materials from different departments in my Outlook calendar? So people stop complaining in case I put important material into a meeting so people are able to prepare themselves?

Comment: that's the way outlook meetings are designed to work.  You can add mail filters to deal with the invites.  If you are using exchange for the server you might have better luck with a shared calendar, hard to tell with the details we know.

Comment: Can you have meetings only for organizers and make the workshops available on a public page?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.No I don't have  public page. I have JIra and getting now confluence for my Program. But people outside the Programs project who don't have access to a collaboration software, have not access to the material. And often we contribute to other departments meetings but have no chance of updating the material before a presentation, because people refuse to be spammed. (Which I totally understand, but makes my job impossible.) There are workarounds. But in the end it is always a lot of work and often presentations and supporting materials are not up to date, wrong,...

Comment: I am not saying that some people might not find the outlook "standard workflow/use case use full or even necessary. But the absence of options/flexibility, makes this product just terrible.

Comment: I would change my use case if I could =) Anyway I will live with my work arounds. Thanks guys, for the clarifications.